# Using OWIN OAuth middleware and system.web authorization simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, ntlm

I have an existing MVC 5 application that uses Active Directory and NTLM authentication/authorization for the controller actions. I do so by having something similar to this in the project root web.config file. It works as I would expect it to.

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />

<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="MyDomain\MyAuthorizedGroup" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AD">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AD" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now, in the same project, I'm writing a RESTful service with WebAPI. The WebAPI endpoints are to be protected in the code via an OAuth token and an Owin middleware. Specifically, the classes provided by Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth. I have overridden the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider class to expose a token generating endpoint and I've added [Authorize(Roles="..."] attributes to my WebAPI endpoints to validate the roles that are in the token. All of this works too, but only when I've disabled the existing NTLM authentication.

And that's a problem I haven't solved yet. I need to support OAuth for the new WebAPI endpoints, NTLM for the existing MVC 5 controller actions, and also OAuth for some new MVC 5 controller actions, the ones that serve the web pages that will communicate with the WebAPI endpoints.

I've separated the API controllers and the MVC controllers into separate folders in the project / on the disk. With that, here's what I've tried (and sorry for the lack of actual configuration elements; for some reason SO isn't rendering them).

1. location tags in the root web.config. Within the two location tags I'd have  for the folder of OAuth protected controllers, and the auth section I pasted above for the existing NTLM protected controllers. In the path attribute, I've tried using both relative URLs (such as {controllerName}/{action}/{id}) and also the actual folder names on the disk. There were a couple of different errors that I don't remember now but suffice to say I was unable to get this solution to work.
2. Nested web.config files. In the MVC folder I had a web.config that had all of the authentication/authorization/role manager. Then, in the root web.config, I had a system.web element with authentication="None" and no authentication/authorization/role manager elements at all. My expectation was that everything in the project would have no authentication through IIS and would thus be left up to the Owin middleware. Then, the child web.config in the folder with the MVC controllers would override the auth in the parent web.config, but only for the MVC controllers. This didn't work, though. NTLM authentication was being applied to everything, not just the MVC controllers that it shared a subfolder with.

So now, I'm at a loss. Can anyone give any guidance into a way to do this?